# Setting the 'Expires' cookie with Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am taking Udacity's Web Development course with Google Appengine and Python.

I'd like to set a cookie to expire, for example, 29 days from the time it is set. How do I achieve this?

I am assuming it is something like this:

```
def set_cookie(expire):
    self.response.headers.add_header(
        'Set-Cookie', 
        'Expires=%s; Path=/' % (expire_date))
```

What format is the 'Expires' value in? How can I set its expiry to be + 29 days (or minutes, hours, weeks, months, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to add the `Set-Cookie` header manually, instead you can do:

```
import datetime

def yourFunction(...):
    expireTime = datetime.datetime.now()  #Check the docs, about adding 29 days, etc.
    self.response.set_cookie('name', 'value', expires=expireTime, path='/', domain='example.com')
```